# Как обратиться к локальному файлу по ссылке в приложении Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, файлы, javascript, изображения

Доброго времени суток!

Можно-ли получить доступ к локальному файлу из приложения или расширения под Chrome используя пути такого вида:

- file:///C:\Folder\File.jpg
- C:\Folder\File.jpg

При попытке создать объект File() из локальной ссылки появляются ошибки:

- Error: GET chrome-extension://acnoddeoamaikpmmdkehnkppmcgcpfjl/C:ImagesTestcat.jpg net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND
- **Not allowed to load local resource**: C:\Images\myjpeg.jpg

За полным разъяснением этого вопроса смотреть мой ответ.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Приложение или расширение Chrome не может получить доступ к локальному файлу напрямую, так как это было бы серьезным нарушением безопасности. Конечно, это [ограничение можно обойти](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/messaging#native-messaging), как мне объяснили на stackoverflow через **Native host**. Правда, лично я не пробовал этого делать, так как свою проблему решил просто сохранением локальных файлов внутри Indexed BD. Подробнее обо всех известных мне способах хранения файлов и последующей работы с ними читайте далее.

**Работа с файлами через Indexed BD.**

- Как сохранить файл в indexedbd? Ответ с разъяснениями [здесь](http://hacks.mozilla.org/2012/02/storing-images-and-files-in-indexeddb/).
- Как получить файл по сети и сохранить в indexedbd? Ответ [здесь](https://gist.github.com/tantaman/6921973).

**Используем FileSystem API для сохранения и работы с файлами.**

- Справка по [FileSystem API](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/fileSystem).
- Статья о работе с [FileSystem API](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/file/filesystem/).

**Local Storage & Session storage & Cookie Storage**

- Как работать с cookie storage? Справка [здесь](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/cookies).
- Как сохранить  файл в [local storage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19183180/how-to-save-an-image-to-localstorage-and-display-it-on-the-next-page)?
- Как работать с [session storage](https://code.google.com/p/sessionstorage/) (временное хранилище)?

Сами файлы (их объекты) для работы с ними Вы можете получить через **drag&drop** или `<input type="file" />`. Почитать подробнее о том, как это делается с примерами и последующим разбором полетов можно [здесь](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/file/dndfiles/).

Надеюсь, что ответ объяснил хотя бы поверхностно о работе с файлами в приложениях и расширениях Google Chrome.

Answer (score 0):

Тут нужно немного по-другому.
Попробуйте путь

```
file://C:/0.JPG
```